# How do I loop the last action in the Automator app?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, automator

How do I loop the last action in the Automator app, instead of looping the entire workflow?

Answer (score 1):

**Automator** has a **Loop** *action*, which causes the first *action* in the *workflow* to be the next *action* executed; however, it does not have a **Loop** *action* to act only on the last *action*.

Another *option*, if applicable, is to use a **Run AppleScript** *action* or **Run Shell Script** *action* where you can *code* in some form of *looping action*.

If appropriate or applicable, you can add any given *action* more than once. Without knowing what your *workflow* looks like it's hard to advise.